# Why is my dynamically-generated oval becoming a square?

Tags: javascript, html

Thought i had everything looking ok.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

```js
function doit() {
 drawOval(100, 150, 90, 90);
 myOval = document.getElementById("newdiv");
} 

function drawOval(left, top, width, height) {
 if (document.createElement) {
   newdiv=document.createElement("div");
   newdiv.style.position="absolute";
   newdiv.style.left = left+"px";
   newdiv.style.top  = top+"px";
   newdiv.style.width = width+"px";
   newdiv.style.height = height+"px";
   newdiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   newdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
   newdiv.id = 'newdiv';
   document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
   }
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="doit()" value="Do it">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That Oracle link is for Java which is different from JavaScript.

Comment: What part of your code do think think makes it oval? By default DIVs are rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,  you are mixing java and javascript. both are different programming languages. if you want to draw oval you can just update your code following way:

```js
function doit() {
 drawOval(160,80,50);
 myOval = document.getElementById("newdiv");
} 

function drawOval(width, height, radius) {
 if (document.createElement) {
   newdiv=document.createElement("div");
   newdiv.style.width = width+"px";
   newdiv.style.height = height+"px";
   newdiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   newdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
   newdiv.style.borderRadius = radius+"%"
   newdiv.id = 'newdiv';
   document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
   }
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="doit()" value="Do it">
```

Comment: Thank you for identifying the mixing of java language types and for suggesting the correct code

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your styles that would result in an oval. You need `border-radius`, probably different for opposing corners:

```js
function doit() {
 drawOval(10, 65, 90, 90);
 myOval = document.getElementById("newdiv");
} 

function drawOval(left, top, width, height) {
 if (document.createElement) {
   newdiv=document.createElement("div");
   newdiv.style.position="absolute";
   newdiv.style.left = left+"px";
   newdiv.style.top  = top+"px";
   newdiv.style.width = width+"px";
   newdiv.style.height = height+"px";
   newdiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   newdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
   newdiv.style.borderRadius = '50px 80px';
   newdiv.id = 'newdiv';
   document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
   }
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="doit()" value="Do it">
```

Comment: Is there a relationship between the height/width input values and the values you selected for `borderRadius`?  I'm unfamiliar with how this property works.  I guess I'm asking, why `50px 80px`?

Comment: Really I've created an ellipse instead of an oval. I just needed values greater than half the respective dimensions. An oval out of a square with 50% radius becomes a circle, so 45px would've yielded that.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply border-radius at 50%, so all borders will be the same.

```js
function doit() {
 drawOval(100, 150, 90, 90);
 myOval = document.getElementById("newdiv");
} 

function drawOval(left, top, width, height) {
 if (document.createElement) {
   newdiv=document.createElement("div");
   newdiv.style.position="absolute";
   newdiv.style.left = left+"px";
   newdiv.style.top  = top+"px";
   newdiv.style.width = width+"px";
   newdiv.style.height = height+"px";
   newdiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   newdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
   // This will do the trick
   newdiv.style.borderRadius = '50%';
   newdiv.id = 'newdiv';
   document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
   }
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="doit()" value="Do it">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have your `width` twice the size of `height` for a better result (horizontal one).

Then, the oval shape is created with the CSS `border-radius` property. So to apply that in JavaScript you have to use it as,

`newdiv.style.borderRadius = "50%";`

You can try the same thing as `width`/`height`

Try the code snippet below. Adjust the values and get your own oval shape.

```js
function doit() {
 drawOval("90", "100", "100", "50");
 myOval = document.getElementById("newdiv");
} 

function drawOval(left, top, width, height) {
 if (document.createElement) {
   newdiv=document.createElement("div");
   newdiv.style.position="absolute";
   newdiv.style.borderRadius = "50%";
   newdiv.style.left  = left+"px";
   newdiv.style.top  = top+"px";
   newdiv.style.width = width+"px";
   newdiv.style.height = height+"px";
   newdiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   newdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
   newdiv.id = 'newdiv';
   document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
   }
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="doit()" value="Do it">
```